# Example of promise without asynchronous code?

Tags: javascript, promise, callback

I am trying to understand the mechanism for promises. Specifically what all can we pass to the first parameter (usually called resolve). for example:

```
function getFoo(url){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        let httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpRequest.open('GET', url);
        httpRequest.onload = function(){
            if(httpRequest ===200) {resolve(httpRequest.responseText);
            } else{ reject(Error(httpRequest.status));}
        }
        httpRequest.send();
    });
}
```

I am trying to build my own function that could benefit from promise (All the exapmples use either setTimeout or ajax code). Can anyone provide a simple example of a regular function using promise (even if the mechanism isnt needed in that case) just so that I can build my own functions that can pass something to the resolve callback? Thanks

for example:

```
function getFoo(param){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        ????myFoo () { ...return...}
         resolve(myFoo);

            } else{ reject(???);}
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `what all can we pass to the first parameter (usually called resolve)` literally anything. A promise is an object that represents an eventual value. `resolve` is how you define what that value is.

Comment: `All the exapmples use either setTimeout or ajax code` ... have you seen any code that uses `SubtleCrypto` - that's all promise based - and why would you use promises for synchronous code - that's just odd

Answer (score 0):

what all can we pass to the first parameter (usually called resolve)

resolve accepts only one parameter, but you can pass anything to the parameter, it can be an array, object, function ... basically any datatype supported by javascript.

Below is a simple promise example.

PS Note: A promise object will be invoked only when you call the then function, and it's the then function that accepts the callback for resolve and rejects.

```
function callPromise() {

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  // do a thing, possibly async, then…

  if (true) {
    resolve("Stuff worked!");
  }
  else {
    reject(Error("It broke"));
  }
});

}

callPromise().then(function(success){
   console.log(success);
}, function(error)
{
  console.log(error);
})
```